# What's the best associative container for grouping data

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store rows of data with parameters date, group1, group2, group3, analytics1, analytics2, analytic 3 into some sort of associative container.  I will need to aggregate the analytics in 3 ways:

1. based on date (think of it like a group by in SQL)
2. based on group1, group2, group3
3. based on date, group1, group2, group3

There will be some simple math done after the data has been grouped. What would be the best data structure for something like this.  I was thinking of doing a multimap(vector, vector) with key and value both being vectors, key is a vector of the form (date, group1, group2, group3) and value is a vector of the form (analytics1, analytics2, analytics3).  This way it will be at its most granular level but I'm pretty sure I'll still end up having to do 3 separate iteratings to take care of the groupings.  Is there a faster alternative approach?

Comment: Why not use an SQL database?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're after but have a look at boost::multi_index_array

Comment: @flyx: I think that's what he's going to wind up building.

Comment: it's already in sql, I don't really make those calls

Comment: You have two distinct sets: the (group1, group2, group3) set, and the (date, group1, group2, group3).  You can derive the (date) set by aggregating over the keys in the (date, group1, group2, group3) set (or you could have a third set based on just the date — your choice; your machine's memory may control this).  If the data is in SQL, can't you get the DBMS to do the donkey work for you?  'Twould be better than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may want 'Boost Multi-index Containers Library' (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)